# Jszip and jszip-utils Meteor - currupt image files when saving a zip file

Tags: meteor, corrupt, jszip

Hi I am attempting to save image files using JSZip and JSZip-utils.

I can package up the files but when trying to view them in windows the files are corrupt.

Here is my code:

```js
//returns a Jquery Promise (binary content for use in JSZip)
if (currentViewOption == "f"|| currentViewOption == "t") {
  const downloadPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(frontImgUrl, (err, data) => resolve(data));
  });
  zip.file(frontImgID, downloadPromise);
}

if (currentViewOption == "b"||currentViewOption == "t") {
  const downloadPromise2 = new Promise(resolve => {
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(backImgUrl, (err, data) => resolve(data));
  });          
  zip.file(backImgID, downloadPromise2);
}

var now = Helpers.prettifyDateTime(new Date());

//generation of the zip, and send to the users browser
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob", compression: "DEFLATE"})
  .then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "VPI Images_" + now + ".zip");
  }, function(err){
    console.log(err)
});
```

I would be very grateful if someone could assist, I have spent too long on this already.

Thanks in Advance - Mark

Answer (score 0):

I am using blob:true option while adding a file to zip.

```
zip.file("filename", data, {blob: true});
```

and while creating zip, i am not using compression, i am using this.

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content){
                    saveAs(content, "zipfilename");
                });
```

Maybe you need to specify type while using zip.file like this

```
zip.file("filename", data, {blob:true, type:"img/png"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "binary: true" instead of "blob: true"